# Thread argument printing garbage values

Tags: c, multithreading

I was trying a simple program on threads passing the arguments.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<malloc.h>

#define NUMTHREADS 5

typedef struct _data_t{
        int data;
        char* name;
}_data;

void* mythread(void* arg){
        _data* mydata = (struct _data_t*) arg;
        printf("\n no : %d name : %s \n",mydata->data,mydata->name);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
        pthread_t tid[NUMTHREADS];
        _data mydata;
        mydata.data = 100;
        mydata.name = "Netapp";
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<NUMTHREADS;i++){
                pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,&mythread,(void*)&mydata);
        }
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

Output :

angus@ubuntu:~/angus/thread$ ./a.out

no : 0 name : 1�I��^H��H���PTI��0@

no : 0 name : 1�I��^H��H���PTI��0@

no : 0 name : 1�I��^H��H���PTI��0@

no : 0 name : 1�I��^H��H���PTI��0@

no : 0 name : 1�I��^H��H���PTI��0@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `main` terminates, `mydata` ceases to exist, but the threads are still running and accessing it.

You should either wait for the spawned threads to terminate before you exit `main` (using `pthread_join`), or define `mydata` so that it outlives scope of `main`.